# Why is Leaflet Ajax not processing and displaying GeoJSON data?

Tags: json, ajax, leaflet, gis, geojson

I have been trying for weeks to get Leaflet Ajax to accept data requests from the Land Information New Zealand (LINZ) API without success.

I have a valid key (not included in the snippet) and have tried several tests to load this data in. Other datasets from the LINZ API do not worth either.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

    <!-- Leaflet Ajax -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src="./js/leaflet.ajax.js"></script>

    <div id="map"></div>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        map = L.map('map').setView([-41.29132, 174.77931],16)
        var OpenTopoMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 17,
            attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
        });
        OpenTopoMap.addTo(map)

        property_tiles_link = "https://data.linz.govt.nz/services/query/v1/vector.json?key=KEY_GOES_HERE&layer=50804&x=172.61706383056807&y=-43.57379489129212&max_results=3&radius=10000&geometry=true&with_field_names=true"
        geojson = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(property_tiles_link).addTo(map)
        console.log(geojson)
        overlays = {
            "geojson": geojson
        }
        basemaps = {
            "OpenTopoMap": OpenTopoMap
        }
        L.control.layers(basemaps, overlays).addTo(map)
    </script>
</body>
```

The code snippet results in this output:
[image: screenshot]

Looking through the logged GeoJSON object does not seem to show any successfully parsed data. The error message in Firefox translates roughly to "The configuration of HTML characters hasn't been declared. The document will show 'rubbish' text in some configurations of the browser."

Any ideas would be super helpful!

An example of the response:

```
{
  "vectorQuery": {
    "layers": {
      "50804": {
        "crs": {
          "type": "name",
          "properties": {
            "name": "EPSG:4326"
          }
        },
        "field_names": ["id", "title_no", "status", "type", "land_district", "issue_date", "guarantee_status", "estate_description", "number_owners", "spatial_extents_shared"],
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
          "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  [175.4776337167, -41.2221699],
                  [175.4782420833, -41.2225527833],
                  [175.4801549333, -41.2237566167],
                  [175.476269, -41.2259343],
                  [175.47357595, -41.22444375],
                  [175.4776337167, -41.2221699]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          },
          "distance": 0,
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "id": 1468560,
            "title_no": "WN53B/277",
            "status": "LIVE",
            "type": "Freehold",
            "land_district": "Wellington",
            "issue_date": "1998-04-16 00:00:00",
            "guarantee_status": "Guarantee",
            "estate_description": "Fee Simple, 1/1, Lot 1 Deposited Plan 85426, 110,945 m2",
            "number_owners": 1,
            "spatial_extents_shared": false
          },
          "id": 1191838
        }, {
          "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  [175.48005638330002, -41.2282570333],
                  [175.48105425000003, -41.2286012667],
                  [175.4789359, -41.2297867333],
                  [175.47874645, -41.2298923],
                  [175.4767530167, -41.2310074667],
                  [175.47604405, -41.2314040667],
                  [175.47550265, -41.23170695000001],
                  [175.4749415833, -41.2320208833],
                  [175.4745023167, -41.2322666333],
                  [175.474015, -41.2317699833],
                  [175.4735909, -41.23133785000001],
                  [175.4735833, -41.2313303667],
                  [175.4732046667, -41.23094425],
                  [175.4728425667, -41.2305752833],
                  [175.4725057833, -41.2302328833],
                  [175.4722412333, -41.2299625],
                  [175.4719444667, -41.2296600833],
                  [175.4715930333, -41.22930195],
                  [175.47127355, -41.2289763667],
                  [175.4712437333, -41.2289459833],
                  [175.4708617, -41.22855675],
                  [175.4704157833, -41.2281024167],
                  [175.4699766167, -41.227654983300006],
                  [175.4692410167, -41.2269055],
                  [175.4692395833, -41.2269040667],
                  [175.46921793330003, -41.2268834667],
                  [175.4718439333, -41.2254143333],
                  [175.4733724167, -41.2245578167],
                  [175.48005638330002, -41.2282570333]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          },
          "distance": 134,
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "id": 2348803,
            "title_no": "WN103/58",
            "status": "LIVE",
            "type": "Freehold",
            "land_district": "Wellington",
            "issue_date": "1899-10-23 00:00:00",
            "guarantee_status": "Guarantee",
            "estate_description": "Fee Simple, 1/1, Lot 75 Deposited Plan 579, 409,390 m2",
            "number_owners": 1,
            "spatial_extents_shared": true
          },
          "id": 5113879
        }, {
          "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  [175.48005638330002, -41.2282570333],
                  [175.48105425000003, -41.2286012667],
                  [175.4789359, -41.2297867333],
                  [175.47874645, -41.2298923],
                  [175.4767530167, -41.2310074667],
                  [175.47604405, -41.2314040667],
                  [175.47550265, -41.23170695000001],
                  [175.4749415833, -41.2320208833],
                  [175.4745023167, -41.2322666333],
                  [175.474015, -41.2317699833],
                  [175.4735909, -41.23133785000001],
                  [175.4735833, -41.2313303667],
                  [175.4732046667, -41.23094425],
                  [175.4728425667, -41.2305752833],
                  [175.4725057833, -41.2302328833],
                  [175.4722412333, -41.2299625],
                  [175.4719444667, -41.2296600833],
                  [175.4715930333, -41.22930195],
                  [175.47127355, -41.2289763667],
                  [175.4712437333, -41.2289459833],
                  [175.4708617, -41.22855675],
                  [175.4704157833, -41.2281024167],
                  [175.4699766167, -41.227654983300006],
                  [175.4692410167, -41.2269055],
                  [175.4692395833, -41.2269040667],
                  [175.46921793330003, -41.2268834667],
                  [175.4718439333, -41.2254143333],
                  [175.4733724167, -41.2245578167],
                  [175.48005638330002, -41.2282570333]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          },
          "distance": 134,
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "id": 4177014,
            "title_no": "94991",
            "status": "LIVE",
            "type": "Leasehold",
            "land_district": "Wellington",
            "issue_date": "2003-06-10 09:00:00",
            "guarantee_status": "Guarantee",
            "estate_description": "Leasehold, 1/1, Lot 75 Deposited Plan 579, 409,390 m2",
            "number_owners": 1,
            "spatial_extents_shared": true
          },
          "id": 5116291
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the response of your API?

Comment: I don't know how to do that with leaflet ajax. I've updated the main post with an expanded version - I thought that was the response object?

Comment: Just enter your API URL in the nav bar of your browser and see what response payload you get.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip! The post has been updated to include a basic example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Leaflet-ajax plugin](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) expects directly a GeoJSON compliant object in the loaded data, whereas in the sample response you show, the structure of the response is:

```json
{
  "vectorQuery": {
    "layers": {
      [layerId]: {
        // GeoJSON FeatureCollection
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore you have to convert this data into a GeoJSON object first. Here in this case it looks quite simple, as you just have to extract the FeatureCollection. You can use leaflet-ajax `middleware` option to perform this conversion between the reception of the data and before it is processed to be transformed into Leaflet layers:

```js
new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("url", {
  middleware(rawData) {
    // Extract the GeoJSON FeatureCollection
    const layerId = 50804;
    return rawData.vectorQuery.layers[layerId];
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves months of struggling to get this working.

Comment: Thank you for your nice feedback! I am glad it helps you moving forward ;-)